# How to improve the learning rate of an MLP for regression when tanh is used with the Adam solver as an activation function?

Tags: regression, mlp, learning-rate

I'm trying to use an MLP to approximate a smooth function f : R^3 -> R, that takes a point in space as an argument, and returns a scalar value.

The MLP architecture has a 3-dimensional (for 3 point coordinates) input layer, N hidden layers and a single linear scalar output layer, since the output should be the function value:

```
   x  x      x
x  x  x      x
x  x  x  ... x  x
x  x  x      x
   x  x      x
```

I'm using the tanh activation function because I want the model (MLP) to be continuously differential.

I'm playing with different hidden layer architectures, using the Adam solver, and I get this behavior for the MSE loss

[image]

The maximal validation error that I get with this mean MSE loss is 99.982942% - is this generally considered accurate for regression?

For the network with hidden layers (16, 16, 16, 16, 16), the error stagnates but then drops and oscillates. I suspect the oscillation is due to the diminishing gradients when using the tanh activation function for learning, is this true?

How to set/improve the learning rate, are there techniques that prevent oscillations when the solver (Adam, SGD, ...) approaches the optimum?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @spectre: I'm interested in setting/improving the learning rate, so that I avoid the oscillations when the solver approaches the optimum. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to set the optimum value of hyperparameters (weather it be learning rate, no of layers, activation function etc.) you should look into [Keras Tuner](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/).

The reason as to why the learning curve is oscillating is not clear to me without seeing your code/data. But if you want to set an optimum value of learning rate then look into Kera Tuner provided you **ARE** using keras + tensorflow.

If you are using PyTorch as the frame work then you could use any of the following HP tuning methods/packages:

1.)[Ray Tune](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/hyperparameter_tuning_tutorial.html)

2.) [Optuna](https://optuna.org/)

3.) [Auto Pytorch](https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch)

4.) [BoTorch](https://botorch.org/)

There are many more packages. You could do a google search.

**Cheers!**

Comment: I'm using Pytorch, is there something equivalent? When I reduce the learning rate of the solver, the oscillations reduce significantly (as expected)....

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your comment